# Rails: can Zeus read the .env file?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, foreman, env, zeus

I'm using [Zeus](https://github.com/burke/zeus) to pre-load my Rails environment as a replacement for developing with Foreman. But Zeus isn't picking up values from my .env file.

Is it possible for Zeus to do this?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the dotenv gem :

https://github.com/bkeepers/dotenv

In your Gemfile

```
gem 'dotenv', groups: [:development, :test]
```

`bundle install` and restart Zeus.

Your `.env` variables will now be loaded in development environment which Zeus preloads.